# ¿Cómo Integrar MercadoPago con Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic, mercadopago, ionic2

Es posible Integrar la api de mercadopago sobre ionic2?

Estuve buscando en toda la red pero no hay algo consiso que ayude a utiliza correctamente la api sobre este framework.

Comment: pudieras compartir como pudiste migrarla a angular 2.

Comment: No pude migrar para angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

No hay una version oficial para ionic2 aun, pero quizás la versión para ionic 1 te puede servir, quizás haya que hacer algunos cambios pero con el código fuente libre no debería ser tan grave.

https://github.com/mercadopago/px-hybrid

Answer (score 1):

El plugin de Cordova px-hybrid solo sirve para Ionic 1 y esta hecha con AngularJS, habría que migrarla a angular 2 para que funcione en Ionic 2.

Como no encontré nada para Ionic 2, implementé la API con el SDK en Javascript en la App de Ionic y para la parte del server (generar el payment), usé el SDK en PHP. Lleva bastante tiempo unir las partes pero funciona perfectamente.